# how do I make my SDcard formatable again?

Tags: sd-card, mbr

I've accidentally formatted a SD micro card by overwriting it with zeroes. Now, I cannot do anything with it, can't copy files to it nor files from it.

I have tried this:

- 1. Quick and full format
- 2. Using Windows native software
- 3. Using third party software

Main question:

1. How do I make the **SD card** readable and writeable again?

Sub question:

2. Should I do some restore of the MBR or something, in order to achieve that?
3. Do SD cards even **HAVE** an MBR?

Note: The card is not encrypted, nor locked. When attempting to format with Windows format, it gives an error message after n half hour of trying: "This can not be formatted
It's a Verbatim SD micro, capacity 500GB.

The card is visible by the computer, but that's about the only good thing. The type is RAW.

Comment: What was the third-party software? Was it [SD Memory Card Formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/)?

Comment: nope. it was partition mini wizard. why?

Comment: Okay, so after the whole DISKPART f.... up, i did use ***SD Memory  card formatter*** and it worked in seconds. I'm in the process of copying 64gb to it, which takes hours, so it doesn't seem to have worked well. Let's see iif my phone accepts it.

Comment: The largest Verbatim microSD card I can see listed on their website is [128GB](https://www.verbatim-europe.co.uk/en/prod/microsdxc-128gb-memory-card-class-10-44085/), which makes the 500GB suspicious. Maybe an article like [How to Identify and Test Fake Memory Cards](https://photographylife.com/fake-memory-cards) would help.

Answer (score 1):

**Format SD card to NTFS in Windows 10 with Diskpart**

First open Command Prompt as an administrator (you can do this through the Start button). Now you need to enter some commands:

1. "diskpart" then press Enter.
2. "list volume" then press Enter.
3. Type "select volume x", where x is the drive letter, then press Enter.
4. Type "format fs=ntfs quick", press Enter.
   (this may take some time, do not interrupt the process)

---

if this task takes to long, you can abort it using diskpart:

1. start a Command promt in administrative mode (like before)
2. type "diskpart"
3. then type "list disk"
4. "select disk X" (while X is your drive number of the SD card.
5. "offline disk"
   Now the formatting process has been canceled. Continue to enter "online disk" in order to use it again.

cheers,
Radi

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. Diskpart indicates it's healthy, the FS is  RAW, but it's sitting from *"0 percent completed"* for like, 10 minutes already. I wil keep u updated.

Comment: Allright i will reproduce the issue :) brb

Comment: i edited my post. 
*"format fs=ntfs quick"* this worked for me.

Comment: The process is already underway. How do I interrupt it without damage? it took about 15 mins to get at "1 percent completed"

Comment: no problem you can take the disk offline. start another terminal and write: diskpart > list disk > select disk X > offline disk

Comment: it says: Virtual Disk Service Error: the operation is not supported on removeable media.

Comment: im getting out of options here :) you could wait till it finishes... or you plug it out and back in, (what i would not do) and try to format it with the quick format command above.

Comment: Yes. Thanks anyway. I just whish you had added the quick option in your answer in the first place. Because it's at *9 percent in almost an hour :( :( I guess i should be grateful it works at all....... SO FAR at least......

Comment: yeah you are right, sorry for that :)

Comment: the ADDITION about "offline disk" .....**DOES NOT WORK** .... like ....**at all**. You should seriously remove it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104999/discussion-between-radi-and-gngrwtch).

Comment: what about? your abortive measure doesn't work.

Comment: you have to select Disk 1, 2, 3, or whatever number your disk has, (for the abortion comand) works for me tough.

Comment: i did. it still didnt work

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaand now it tells me it didn't format jacksh.... because *"the volume is too large."* AAAAAARRRGGGGH!   go figure, **after 6 hours!!!**

Answer (score 1):

Try to format it in your camera, then to the PC.
Worked for 2 SD cards that I somehow ended up changing to 'RAW'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).